# Next.JS & JEST - publicRuntimeConfig undefined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, next.js

I am getting 'publicRuntimeConfig undefined' error while running unit test cases using next.js and Jest

I am using next 9.1.1.I've tried below solutions but it's not working.

- I have set config in jest.setup.js also.Please see below code

  ```
  import { setConfig } from 'next/config';
  import config  from './next.config';
  setConfig(config.publicRuntimeConfig);
  ```
- I've tried using jest mock in test case file.

  ```
  jest.mock('next/config', () => () => ({
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
      key: 'abc
    }
  }));
  ```

Answer (score 17):

It works for me calling jest.mock before the Component Test Case like you mentioned:

```
jest.mock('next/config', () => () => ({
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    SOME_VARIABLE_HERE: 'whatever-you-want-here'
  }
}))
```

I didn't need to create a jest.setup or any other stuff. Those are my dependencies:

```
"astroturf": "^0.10.4",
"autoprefixer": "^10.0.0",
"axios": "^0.20.0",
"date-fns": "^2.16.1",
"js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
"next": "^9.5.3",
"next-cookies": "^2.0.3",
"node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"styled-components": "^5.2.0"
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.0.4",
"babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.11.1",
"jest": "^26.4.2"
```

Comment: Great answer! However, if you want to run the mock-up for every test, then you may want to have the logic live in a `jest.setup.js` then call in the `jest.config.js`


```javascript
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
 setupFiles: ['./jest.setup.js'],
}
```

```javascript
// jest.setup.js
jest.mock('next/config', () => () => ({
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    SOME_VARIABLE_HERE: 'whatever-you-want-here'
  }
}))
```

Answer (score 13):

I solved this problem by creating a `jest.setup.js` file and adding this line of code

```
// jest.config.js

module.exports = {
  // Your config
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
};
```

And add

```
// jest.setup.js

import { setConfig } from 'next/config'
import config from './next.config'

// Make sure you can use "publicRuntimeConfig" within tests.
setConfig(config)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also if you want to mock and change the publicRuntimeConfig variable's value per test block, you can spy on getConfig function like this:

```
const getConfig = jest.spyOn(require('next/config'), 'default');

getConfig.mockImplementation(() => ({
    publicRuntimeConfig: { variable: 'value' },
}));

describe('describe block', () => {
    it('should do something', () => {
        getConfig.mockImplementation(() => ({
            publicRuntimeConfig: { variable: 'other value' },
        }));

        // your test logic go here
    });
});
```

This also works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having problems with the "mock publicRuntimeConfig" solution, for me it solved it manually parsing my dotenv file inside jest setup file and assigning it to the mock.

```
// jest.config.js
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

const { parsed } = dotenv.config({
    path: ".env.local"
});

jest.mock('next/config', () => () => ({
    publicRuntimeConfig: parsed
}))
```